# NDK load assets

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm using this method to load assets in NDK:

```
jclass localRefCls = myEnv->FindClass("(...)/AssetLoaderHelper");
helperClass = reinterpret_cast<jclass>(myEnv->NewGlobalRef(localRefCls));
myEnv->DeleteLocalRef(localRefCls);

helperMethod1ID = myEnv->GetStaticMethodID(helperClass, "getFileData", "(Ljava/lang/String;)[B");

...

myEnv->PushLocalFrame(10);

jstring pathString = myEnv->NewStringUTF(path);
jbyteArray data = (jbyteArray) myEnv->CallStaticObjectMethod(helperClass, helperMethod1ID, pathString);

char* buffer = new char[len];
myEnv->GetByteArrayRegion(data, 0, len, (jbyte*)buffer);

myEnv->DeleteLocalRef(pathString);
myEnv->DeleteLocalRef(data);

jobject result;
myEnv->PopLocalFrame(result);
myEnv->DeleteLocalRef(result);

return buffer;
```

in java:

```
public static byte[] getFileData(String path)
{
InputStream asset = getAsset(path); //my method using InputStream.open

byte[] b = null;
try
{
    int size = asset.available();
    b = new byte[size];
    asset.read(b, 0, size);
    asset.close();
}
catch (IOException e1)
{
    Log.e("getFileData", e1.getMessage());
}

return b;
}
```

It works but when i load many assets there is crash or system locks. Am I making any mistake or someone knows better method to load assets to NDK? Perhaps it is only problem with low memory in my device?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure on your exact problem, but I may offer a alternative solution to opening assets JNI side:

1. Java side create a AssetFileDescriptor for each file in question (call this fd for now on
2. Pass the value of fd.getFileDescriptor(), fd.getStartOffset(), and fd.getLength() to a JNI function
3. JNI side you can now use fdopen(), fseek(), fread(), etc. using the information from #2
4. Don't forget to call fd.close() after your JNI work

Hope that helps

Comment: And what if I'm using a library in ndk that needs a file path. For example sqlite open() function takes the path to the database file. What would be the best solution in that case?

Comment: If you need a path, simply use the path. In your example with sqlite_open(), you'll most likely want something built Java-side using getExternalStorageDirectory() then passed via JNI and ultimately to SQLite.

Comment: No, I meant, how to open an sqlite database that was included as a resource with the apk.

Comment: Then you need to do as described in my answer.